# Parsing an array inside of a string to string array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need your help parsing a string that contains an array inside to string array, is it posible? 
Currently I'm using split to do it but I think that is not the correct way..

Here an example of what my string contains:

```
["SR RODRIGUEZ SE LO LLEVA  ,,, PIL  4_45  ","COMENTARIOS"]
```

I hope you can help me guys, I've been stuck with this problem for an entire day..

Comment: `String.split()` is actually probably the right way to do it. If you need more help, please show some examples of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: can you post the end result you want?

Comment: This String myString = "["SR RODRIGUEZ SE LO LLEVA  ,,, PIL  4_45  ","COMENTARIOS"]";
to
this String[] array= {"SR RODRIGUEZ SE LO LLEVA  ,,, PIL  4_45  ", "COMENTARIOS"};
System.out.println( array[0] );
System.out.println( array[1] );

Comment: Given example at your comment is incorrect, it could not even compile. Provide the working example data set.

Comment: I'm consuming a WS that returns me a String that contains this: ["SR RODRIGUEZ SE LO LLEVA  ,,, PIL  4_45  ","COMENTARIOS"]
I want to cast it to String array or something else that allows me to access to every String

Comment: `String[] strings = String.split(",")` is what I believe you're looking for

Comment: did you want only dobule quoted string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want string array of double quoted string. Look at this:

```
String str = "\"SR RODRIGUEZ SE LO LLEVA  ,,, PIL  4_45  \",\"COMENTARIOS\",\"abc\"";
    String res[] = str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
    Arrays.stream(res).forEach(st -> System.out.println(st));
```

Comment: Just to know, this solution works if theres doublequotes (escaped) inside a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can achive what you desire with below :

```
    String myString = "[\"SR RODRIGUEZ SE LO LLEVA ,,, PIL 4_45 \",\"COMENTARIOS\"]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])*\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        myList.add(matcher.group());
    }

    myList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output :

```
"SR RODRIGUEZ SE LO LLEVA ,,, PIL 4_45 "
"COMENTARIOS"
```

Comment: Just to know, this solution works if theres doublequotes (escaped) inside a string?

Comment: No, if quotes not escaped, code is not even compile. You can not write a string like String myStr = "["test"]";
If you read your string from external source (file, network etc.) it works.
Excepted answer escaped quotes too.

Comment: I mean this: ["\"value \"\"", "other \" "] note that it supposed to be two values, you regex capture it correctly?

Comment: I paste it into a file and read it from file with String myString = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("mystr.txt")).get(0);
It gives the output : "\"value \"\"" and "other \" " . I dont know is that what u need?

Comment: Oh yes, I just wanted to know if it got the escaped quotes or splited it +1 mate, idk regex

Comment: I'm glad to helps u mate